# How is $a = - b$ symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R3 = {(a, b)} | {a = b}$ or ${a = - b}$ is a relation on set of integers

Which of the following pairs does R3 contains?

${(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,-1),(2,2)}$

I know that $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$ and $(1,-1)$ are in $R3$. The thing is: The book says it's a symmetric relation. I know that that for each pair $(a,b)$, if it's symmetric, $(b,a)$ must be in the relation, so $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ are fine. I'm just struggling to find out why $(1,-1)$ does so, because I guess that $(-1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are different.

If someone could explain me this I'd be thankfull.

Comment: What's $A$? Is that the relation?

Comment: @kingW3 Sorry, they are only pairs

Comment: I don't quite understand so what's the relation? You wrote $(a, b) $ but what are $a, b$ here?

Comment: Relation R3 is between which sets? The question is incomplete

Comment: @LivinJoseph set of integers

Comment: @EricTowers sorry, set of integers

Comment: @EricTowers The book gives only 5 pairs and asks wich of them are in R3

Comment: The pair $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ is in R3 because $a=-b.$ Check $(-1)=-(1).$

Comment: Excellent.  So you know there are more elements of the relation that the three you identified.  Does the definition of symmetric require that the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ both be listed as examples for R3 on this page?  Or is it required that both be members of the relation regardless of what was presented as examples here?

Comment: @LivinJoseph It only asks which of those 5 pairs are in R3. It's fine to find them. Then it asks if it's symmetric or assymetric, and I know it is  symmetric, I just can't understand why because of the pair (1, -1)

Comment: @LivinJoseph I already did so. I was just wondering why it is Symmetric

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry I did not understand quite well

Comment: Is $(-1,1) \in {}$R3 even though it is not listed as an example?

Comment: @EricTowers Nice, I don't know for sure. I was trying to visualize it just like (1,1) because it's basically the same thing if I do the 'reverse', but I am not sure about (1,-1).

Comment: @EricTowers Also, thank you so much for your help, I'll try to understand it better

Comment: @EricTowers I think I got it now.. based on the answer now I see that R3 is symmetric. But still thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the condition $a=-b$. This conditions can be easily transformed into the symmetric condition $b=-a$ by multiplying both sides with $-1$. So in fact
$$ a= -b \Leftrightarrow b=-a$$
From this you can easily deduce that your relation is symmetric.

In your example: $(-1,1)$ is clearly in the relation, as $-1 = -(1)$. But a relation $R$ being symmetric just means that if $aRb$ then also $bRa$. This does *not* mean $a=b$, as you seem to imply in your question.